# How can I deploy an Android application internally in an organization?

Tags: android, deployment, webserver, mime-types

I would like to deploy an Android application internally in an organization.

For the moment while developing the application, I have used e-mail to spread my application. Then the user has to install the Android SDK, install a driver for his phone and finally run the `adb install MyApplication.apk` to install the application.

Is there any better ways to deploy Android applications internally? Is it even possible to manage updates?

I read on a [forum](http://forums.t-mobile.com/t5/ARCHIVED-Market-Downloads-Games/Non-Market-applications-How-to-install/m-p/9935#M629) that applications can be deployed on a webserver. Then the user only has to download the application for installing. But when I tried to simply upload an `.apk` file to my webserver and visit the URL using the browser on my phone I got this message:

```
<Uknown>
mydomain.com
Cannot download. The content is not supported on the phone.
```

So how can I fix this? Is there any kind of MIME-type I have to set on the webserver? Doing the same thing as described in the link above on http://slideme.org/sam2.apk works fine, and the installation starts.

The only thing I can find about this on *Android Developers* [Publishing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html)
 is:

> You can publish your application using a hosted service such as Android Market or through a web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try application/vnd.android.package-archive as the MIME type.